# Как установить пометку checked в form:radiobuttons?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, form, radio

при генерации формы на jsp странице использую тег form:radiobuttons, в который передаю список с параметрами.

```
<form:radiobuttons path="face_id" items="${face_id}" delimiter="<br />" required="true"/>
```

вопрос, как можно сделать в генерируемом списке предварительно выбранное значение (свойство checked в html)?

Comment: если можно как-то получить значение value для каждого значения, то можно было бы установить условие типа: checked="${this.value == 'точтонадо' ? 'true' : 'false'}", но как его получить не могу найти.

Answer (score 0):

решение: задавать значение "по умолчанию" в java коде, до передачи на jsp страницу.

```
MyDataModel data = new MyDataModel();
Map<Sting, String> face_id = preparedMap.getMap();
data.setFaceId(2);
model.addObject("data", data);
model.addObject("face_id", face_id);
```

Таким образом "по умолчанию" в списке radiobuttons будет выбрано значение с value="2".